# Call JavaScript code from file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, github

I'm currently trying to play a FLAC audio file in HTML and come across this website: https://www.wakamoleguy.com/2014/flac-over-webrtc-with-sipjs/

It wanted me to go download some JavaScript code and add this to the top of the html:

```
<script src="aurora.js"></script>
<script src="flac.js"></script>
<script src="sip.js"></script>
```

After that, I downloaded [flac.js](https://github.com/audiocogs/flac.js), [aurora.js](https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js) and [sip.js](http://sipjs.com/download/). But the problem is that only sip.js came as a file, while the rest came as folders. I don't know if it is possible to call a folder called flac.js or if I can call the index.js inside maybe?

flac.js and aurora.js linked me to a GitHub link, and I'm not sure if I'm meant to be using the code that way they posted it. I have nearly no clue about JavaScript but only want this to work.

Comment: I think you need to run the two steps under "Building" on the github pages to create the .js files, so that you can use them.

Comment: So this question should rather have been how to build a javascript file from github?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Under the "building" and the blue link called "releases page" I found that I could download a pre-built version. So this was actually a simple answer and a stupid question. But thanks for getting me on tracks.

Comment: There are different kinds of build systems and github has many different projects, usually the readme says what to do. But the answer from @Device might be the easiest way for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to "releases" page on github: 
**Aurora.js:** https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js/releases 
**Flac.js:** https://github.com/audiocogs/flac.js/releases

Comment: Thank you, I will remember this to next time I use github.

Comment: And maybe, ask another question or google how to build js from coffe script.

Comment: Yes, but like I said. I had noe clue about how I call a javascript code and youtube videos only showed me how to call javascript codes they made themselves. So I was confused and came here instead.